# Using grep in /etc/passwd to fetch list of users and system users, discriminating both

Tags: command-line, scripts, grep

I want my grep to print a user list from /etc/passwd, and I've studied /etc/login.defs' minmax values for the ones I want my grep to fetch:

```
# Min/max values for automatic uid selection in useradd
#
UID_MIN          1000
UID_MAX         60000
# System accounts
#SYS_UID_MIN          100
#SYS_UID_MAX          999
```

Actual user IDs start at 1000 and finish at 60000, and system user IDs start at 100 and finish at 999.

So I made my script look like this (warning spanish text):

```
2)
echo 
echo "LISTA DE USUARIOS"
cat /etc/passwd | grep -E "*:[*-6][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]:*" | cut -d":" -f1
echo
echo "LISTA DE USUARIOS DEL SISTEMA"
cat /etc/passwd | grep -E "*:[1-9][0-9][0-9]:*" | cut -d":" -f1 
;;
```

It's obviously plain not working and grep is very hard for me so I'm not sure how to make it work. I tried (and always try) reading others' solutions but I think I'll need this one explained to me if I ever want to learn.

If possible I'm trying to avoid perl territory. I can't handle that much yet though I understand what it's famed for.

Anything else you need to know to help me, let me know.

Thanks! (also, first post ever here)

Comment: much easier to use a language that can do arithmetic comparisons e.g. `awk -F: '$3>=1000' /etc/passwd`

Comment: @steeldriver I see, never really learned about that one, will investigate.

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` command does what you want. First, you set the record separator to `:` with `FS=":"`, check if the third element is 1000-60000, and if so, print element 1 (username):

```
awk 'FS=":" {if ($3 > 999 && $3 < 60001) print $1}' < /etc/passwd
```

Comment: ...and fwiw, here's a Perl one-liner that does the same thing: `perl -Mstrict -nE 'my @a=split /:/; if ($a[2] > 999 && $a[2] < 60001){ say $a[0]; }' /etc/passwd
`

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`  version, with arrays. A bit more lengthy but working

```
awk -F':' ' $3 >= 1000 && $1 != "nobody" {i++;humanuser[i]=$1 } $3 < 999 { k++;sysuser[k]=$1} END {printf"****HUMAN USERS\n";for (j=1;j<=i;j++) printf humanuser[j]" "; printf "\n*****SYSTEM USERS\n"; for(m=1;m<=k;m++) printf sysuser[m]" "}' /etc/passwd
```

Sample output:

```
****HUMAN USERS
xieerqi testuser 
*****SYSTEM USERS
root daemon bin sys sync games man lp mail news uucp proxy www-data backup list irc gnats libuuid syslog messagebus usbmux dnsmasq avahi-autoipd kernoops rtkit saned whoopsie speech-dispatcher avahi lightdm colord hplip pulse gdm
```

Comment: You could use `UID_MIN=$(awk '/^#*UID_MIN/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs); SYS_UID_MAX=$(awk '/^#*SYS_UID_MAX/ {print $2}' /etc/login.defs); awk -F':' ' $3 >= '"$UID_MIN"' && $1 != "nobody" {i++;humanuser[i]=$1 } $3 < '"$SYS_UID_MAX"' { k++;sysuser[k]=$1} END {printf"****HUMAN USERS\n";for (j=1;j<=i;j++) printf humanuser[j]" "; printf "\n*****SYSTEM USERS\n"; for(m=1;m<=k;m++) printf sysuser[m]" "}' /etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` with Perl Compatible RegEx (PCRE) :

- To get the usernames with `UID >= 1000` :

  ```
  grep -Po '^[^:]+(?=:[^:]+:\d{4,})' /etc/passwd
  ```
- To get the usernames with `100 <= UID <= 999` :

  ```
  grep -Po '^[^:]+(?=:[^:]+:\d{3})' /etc/passwd
  ```

Here `-P` indicates PCRE, `-o` indicates we are going to take only the matched portion.

- `^[^:]+` gets us the username, everything upto first `:`
- `(?=)` is zero width positive lookahead pattern, we are using this to ensure that we match our desired portion after the username
- `:[^:]+:` matches `:x:` and then `\d{4,}` matches four or more digits (`>=1000`)
- On the other hand `:[^:]+:` matched `:x:` then `\d{3}` matches exactly three digits (`100 to 999`).

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAMER**: The following java answer is for educational purposes and the fun of coding only. If you downvote, explain in the comments why.

**Code**

The code bellow reads each line from `/etc/passwd` , splits that line into strings with `:` as separator, and sorts users depending on their UID into appropriate ArrayLists.

package com.askubuntu.users.serg;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
/**
 * 
 * A program to sort human and system users from /etc/password
 * 
 * @author Serg Kolo
 *
 */
public class UserList {
    private static final String SEPARATOR = "=============";
    private static final int SYS_UID_MAX = 999;
    private static final int UID_MAX = 1000;
    private static final String FILENAME_PASSWD = "/etc/passwd";
    private static final String COLON = ":";
    private static final String NOBODY = "nobody";

    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File(FILENAME_PASSWD);
        try (Scanner readFile = new Scanner(f)) {
            ArrayList<String> humanUsers = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<String> systemUser = new ArrayList<>();

            while (readFile.hasNext()) {
                String[] field = readFile.nextLine().split(COLON);
                int uid = Integer.parseInt(field[2]);

                if (uid >= UID_MAX && (!NOBODY.equals(field[0]))) {
                    humanUsers.add(field[0]);
                } else if (uid <= SYS_UID_MAX) {
                    systemUser.add(field[0]);
                }
            }
            printUsers(humanUsers, "Human Users:");
            printUsers(systemUser, "System Users:");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * print users
     * 
     * @param users
     * @param header
     */
    private static void printUsers(ArrayList<String> users, String header) {
        System.out.println(header);
        System.out.println(SEPARATOR);
        System.out.println(users);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

**Procedure**

1. Save the code above as `userlist.java`
2. Compile and run with your preferred Java IDE. If you prefer command line, do

   ```
   javac UserList.java && java UserList
   ```
3. Output will appear in the console of your IDE

**Sample output**

```
Human Users:
=============
[xieerqi, testuser]
System Users:
=============
[root, daemon, bin, sys, sync, games, man, lp, mail, news, uucp, proxy, www-data, backup, list, irc, gnats, libuuid, syslog, messagebus, usbmux, dnsmasq, avahi-autoipd, kernoops, rtkit, saned, whoopsie, speech-dispatcher, avahi, lightdm, colord, hplip, pulse, gdm, sshd]
```